# bootstrap min css is added in webapp folder still bootstrap css not working in spring mvc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have used bootstrap button in html file and included bootstrap css and bootstrap js in webapp folder but have no bootstrap button effect on UI 
 Am I missing anything to use bootstrap in my project?

Strategic_Consulting.html :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">
    SIGN UP
    </button>

Also added dependency:

<script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.6.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

bootstrap filez included in following path :
src ->main-> webapp->resources -> bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.mic.css

Comment: Add this `<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>` in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file.